# Compute Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I got skunked in computing the time complexity in the inner loop.

Lets consider the following case.

Case 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) - O(n)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)  - O(?);
    {
          //Some thing goes here
    }
}
```

Here the inner loop got executed every time up to value `i`.

So, can I tell like, the complexity for the inner loop is some `O(i)`,

and the overall complexity is `O(N) * O(I); ie: O(N*I)`

Could some one explain in some brief manner, so i can able to understand the computing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The overall time complexity is *O*(*n*²) (in fact, it’s even Θ(*n*²)).

The inner loop has complexity *O*(*i*).  However, *n* is related to *i*, so simply saying that the whole thing has complexity *O*(*ni*) is wrong.  The body of the inner loop will run 0 + 1 + 2 + ⋯ + *n* = (*n*² + *n*) / 2 = Θ(*n*²) times.

Comment: Hi, Could U pls share more. I am new to this performing time complexity..
and also pls share more on the equation, (n² + n) / 2 = Θ(n²) times.
Thanks.

Comment: @user3663241: A comment’s not the best place for me to give a comprehensive introduction to asymptotic notation. However, section 15.5 of [the MIT 6.042 course notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_042JS10_chap15.pdf) is a pretty good description.

Answer (score 1):

Before i go over what you asked for i will explain a simple example.
**We caliculate the time complexity based on how many times the innermost loop is executed** 
consider this case:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    ....
    }
}
```

here the outer loop is executed n times and in every iteration the inner loop is executed n times.
1st iteration - n
2st iteration - n
3st iteration - n
.
.
.
nth iteration -n
so the inner loop is executed  n*n times.so it is O(n^2).
Now we caliculate for the case what you asked for

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
      //Some thing goes here
    }
}
```

Here the Outer loop is executed for n times. and in every i'th iteration the inner loop is executed i times.
1st iteration - 1
2nd iteration - 2
3rd iteration - 3
.
.
.
nth iteration -n
so when we caliculate it would be
1+2+3+.....+n = n(n+1)/2
which is basically O(n^2). :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Got the explanation. But only one question.
n * [n(n+1)/2] is the final result. After doing the math , i can able to get (n^3 + n^2)/2...... May I know, how to arrive to the final ans O(n^2).... Could u pls clarify this one...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Its not n*[n(n+1)/2]. Its just n(n+1)/2 . if it is (n^3+n^2)/2 it would be O(n^3).

Comment: Hi, But this O(N) belongs to the outer loop right, and u did not include in the math. I mean outer loop * inner loop, so it is like n * [n(n+1)]/2 right.... [Here O(n) is the outer loop and n(n+1)/2 is for inner loop.] Pls correct me if am wrong and kindly route me, to understand more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider my first example of code.each loop runs from 0 to n.with out the outer loop the inner loop runs only n times.since we are taking the outer loop into account it became n^2. Think like this "for every single iteration of outer loop the inner loop is executed n times". So it is n times n(n*n). If the outer loop is run for m times and inner loop is for n times then it would be (m*n) i.e. O(m*n).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i got your explanation. But here as per your last reply, O(M)= n and O(N) = n(n+1)/2 right. So O(m*n) = yields n*[n(n+1)/2] right.. I am unable to understand this one. Could u pls add more by taking this reply.... Thanks.